# ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' error when using array.push

Tags: remix, dapps

I'm trying to compile this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract DepositContract {
    // The amount of time (in hours) that the contract will run for
    uint256 constant DURATION_HOURS = 24;
    // The payout rate (in percentage per hour)
    uint256 constant PAYOUT_RATE = 416666666667;

    // Mapping from user address to their deposit balance
    mapping(address => uint256) public deposits;
    // Array of structs that stores the expiration time and amount for each deposit
    Deposit[] public depositsArray;

     // The total amount of deposits in the contract
    uint256 public totalDeposits;

    // The start time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public startTime;

    // The end time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public endTime;

    // Flag to indicate whether the contract is active
    bool public isActive;

    // Struct that stores the expiration time and amount for a single deposit
    struct Deposit {
        uint256 expiration;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    constructor() public {
        // Set the start and end times of the contract
        startTime = now;
        endTime = startTime + DURATION_HOURS * 3600;

        // Set the contract to be active
        isActive = true;
    }

        // Function to compound the user's deposit in the contract
    function compound() public {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the user has a positive deposit balance
        require(deposits[msg.sender] > 0, "You do not have a positive deposit balance.");

        // Calculate the compounded amount
        uint256 compoundedAmount = deposits[msg.sender] * (1 + PAYOUT_RATE / 100);
        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] = compoundedAmount;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += compoundedAmount;
    }
    
    // Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit amount must be greater than zero.");

        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += msg.value;
    }
    // Add a new entry to the depositsArray with the expiration time and amount
      depositsArray.push(Deposit({expiration: now + DURATION_HOURS * 3600,
      amount: msg.value}));
    }


        // Function to withdraw the user's deposit from the contract
    function withdraw() public {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the user has a positive deposit balance
        require(deposits[msg.sender] > 0, "You do not have a positive deposit balance.");

        // Initialize the payout amount
    uint256 payoutAmount = 0;
    // Loop through the depositsArray and calculate the payout amount for each deposit
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < depositsArray.length; i++) {
        // Check that the expiration time has passed for this deposit
        if (depositsArray[i].expiration <= now) {
            // Add the payout amount for this deposit to the total payout amount
            payoutAmount += depositsArray[i].amount * (1 + PAYOUT_RATE / 100);
        }
    }

    // Check that the calculated payout amount is positive
    require(payoutAmount > 0, "There are no deposits available for withdrawal.");
    // Update the deposit balance for the user
    deposits[msg.sender] = 0;
    // Update the total deposits in the contract
    totalDeposits -= payoutAmount;

    // Send the payout amount to the user
    msg.sender.transfer(payoutAmount);
}
    }
```

It seems the way I'm writing my depositsArray code is incorrect because it's giving me this error: `contracts/Fantom Fountain.sol:69:25: ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' depositsArray.push(Deposit({expiration: now + DURATION_HOURS * 3600, ^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a syntax error because you close the `deposit` function with bracket `}` before it ends. The fix : remove the '}' after the line `totalDeposits += msg.value;` in your deposit function :

```
// Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit amount must be greater than zero.");

        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += msg.value;
       // Add a new entry to the depositsArray with the expiration time and amount
       depositsArray.push(Deposit({expiration: now + DURATION_HOURS * 3600,
       amount: msg.value}));
    }
```

---- Update: the above description is not enough for OP to fix so this is the full contract source with the fix, totally compilable with solc-0.6.0 on remix https://remix.ethereum.org/ :

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract DepositContract {
    // The amount of time (in hours) that the contract will run for
    uint256 constant DURATION_HOURS = 24;
    // The payout rate (in percentage per hour)
    uint256 constant PAYOUT_RATE = 416666666667;

    // Mapping from user address to their deposit balance
    mapping(address => uint256) public deposits;
    // Array of structs that stores the expiration time and amount for each deposit
    Deposit[] public depositsArray;

     // The total amount of deposits in the contract
    uint256 public totalDeposits;

    // The start time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public startTime;

    // The end time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public endTime;

    // Flag to indicate whether the contract is active
    bool public isActive;

    // Struct that stores the expiration time and amount for a single deposit
    struct Deposit {
        uint256 expiration;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    constructor() public {
        // Set the start and end times of the contract
        startTime = now;
        endTime = startTime + DURATION_HOURS * 3600;

        // Set the contract to be active
        isActive = true;
    }

        // Function to compound the user's deposit in the contract
    function compound() public {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the user has a positive deposit balance
        require(deposits[msg.sender] > 0, "You do not have a positive deposit balance.");

        // Calculate the compounded amount
        uint256 compoundedAmount = deposits[msg.sender] * (1 + PAYOUT_RATE / 100);
        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] = compoundedAmount;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += compoundedAmount;
    }
    
    // Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit amount must be greater than zero.");

        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += msg.value;
       // Add a new entry to the depositsArray with the expiration time and amount
       depositsArray.push(Deposit({expiration: now + DURATION_HOURS * 3600,
       amount: msg.value}));
    }


        // Function to withdraw the user's deposit from the contract
    function withdraw() public {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the user has a positive deposit balance
        require(deposits[msg.sender] > 0, "You do not have a positive deposit balance.");

        // Initialize the payout amount
    uint256 payoutAmount = 0;
    // Loop through the depositsArray and calculate the payout amount for each deposit
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < depositsArray.length; i++) {
        // Check that the expiration time has passed for this deposit
        if (depositsArray[i].expiration <= now) {
            // Add the payout amount for this deposit to the total payout amount
            payoutAmount += depositsArray[i].amount * (1 + PAYOUT_RATE / 100);
        }
    }

    // Check that the calculated payout amount is positive
    require(payoutAmount > 0, "There are no deposits available for withdrawal.");
    // Update the deposit balance for the user
    deposits[msg.sender] = 0;
    // Update the total deposits in the contract
    totalDeposits -= payoutAmount;

    // Send the payout amount to the user
    msg.sender.transfer(payoutAmount);
}
    }
```

Comment: I tried, it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Hi @StrongThrust, you can copy the code in the updated part of the answer and try again (e.g. on Remix)

Comment: Thank you @minhhn2910. It worked.

Comment: glad that it helps, please mark it as answer if it works for you, thanks